# Pyspark: TypeError: int is required...got type column

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark, nested

I am working with a nested Json structure. I created a dataframe and added a column by doing:

```
jsonDf = jsonDf.withColumn("REPORT_TIMESTAMP", to_timestamp(jsonDF.reportData.timestamp))/
```

All good until here.
Next thing I need to do is derive the year from "REPORT_TIMESTAMP". I have tried various approaches, for instance:

```
jsonDf.withColumn("YEAR", datetime.fromtimestamp(to_timestamp(jsonDF.reportData.timestamp).cast("integer"))
```

that ended with "TypeError: an integer is required (got type Column)

I also tried:

```
jsonDf.withColumn("YEAR", datetime.date.to_timestamp(jsonDF.reportData.timestamp).year)
```

that gave me "AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'to_timestamp'

Can anyone please correct my 2 previous approaches so it works or even suggest another option that I dont have on the radar yet? Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing between Python functions `datetime.date.to_timestamp` and [PySpark functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions).

It's just as simple as `.withColumn('YEAR', F.year('dt'))`

Comment: first of all, thanks a lot! Do you know if there is a similar way to get the day (of month) from a timestamp?

Comment: got it - dayofmonth() it is. Thanks again